# Fixing overlapping polygons within same feature class using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

[image]

I am trying to determine the proper arcpy function or workflow to "Integrate" the borders of overlapping polygons within the same feature class. I am looking for a scripting solution, rather than manual editing in ArcMap, as there will be tens of thousands of these polygons to deal with. (It's important they are not overlapping so I can get the proper area calculations; I don't really care if the vertices are moved, I just want to get rid of the overlap.)

In the picture above, by highlighting one feature I am showing how it is overlapping its neighbour (which is not obvious until you select it or use the Identify tool).

I have played with the Integrate tool, which works for this kind of thing but only between two separate feature classes. Unless I am missing something there ( I have played around with the ranks and XY Tolerance), you can't use Integrtae for this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are two common fixes for this type of problem using ArcGIS:

1. [Snap](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/snap.htm)

   e.g. `Snap_edit (in_features, snap_environment)`
2. Import your featureclass into a file geodatabase and [Create
   Topology Rules](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-topology/geodatabase-topology-rules-and-topology-error-fixes.htm). A `Must Not Overlap` rule and a `Merge` or `Subtract` fix would likely solve the issue. This option does not require scripting.